# Suppress DOMdocument error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using `@$this->dom->loadHTML($page);` to suppress an error but CodeIgniter seems not to respect that...

A series of error is returned in the log

> ERROR - 2012-07-17 16:36:27 --> Severity: Warning  --> DOMDocument::loadHTML():

Is there any way to disable logging only for a piece of code or function?

Comment: Why hide the warning instead of fixing it?

Comment: @AlexLunix What if he's consuming an external web-service?

Comment: Yes.. I can't fix..is a external web-service...

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with 'respecting' the `@`, its got to do with you misunderstanding what `@` does and how CI ties into it.

The `@` symbol in=front of a function tells PHP (not CI) to

> When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

**Reference:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

What that basically means is, that it will 'jump' over the error (otherwise your execution would break on any error). CI will **STILL** log the error if its configured to do so.

You will have to edit CI's config, and define your logging level:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you have enabled error logging, you can set an error threshold to
| determine what gets logged. Threshold options are:
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 1;
```

Comment: Ok. I can disable the log but I'm in a production and logs are important to me to check other problems.. I m looking for a way to suppress just DomDocument->loadhtml. Tks

Comment: @adrianogf, I don't get it, you **want** logs, but you want to **suppress** warnings?  Either be aware of the issue, or turn off all logging. Don't pick and choose error messages to log, that will get you into trouble.